# Selenium Remote Webdriver with remote profile

Tags: python, selenium, remotewebdriver

Is it possible to open a Selenium Remote Webdriver with a specific remote profile (not temporary) in the server?

I have only been able to pass a `browser_profile` from the client. If I instantiate the class without `browser_profile` Selenium creates a new temporary profile in the server.

```
from selenium import webdriver

class Remote(webdriver.Remote):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        capabilities = {_**whatever_}

        super().__init__(
            command_executor='http://HOST:PORT/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=capabilities.copy(),
            browser_profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile(_what?_)
        )
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Did you try with disabling the  firewall  in your server?

Comment: @Prabhakar The firewall is forwarding the port to the server. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question. I've edited it.

Comment: Did you create FireFox profile in your machine? If not please refer http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/ and add the profile to your code an then try

Comment: I can pass profiles _from_ my machine to the server and create temporary profiles _in_ the server. But I want to use profiles _of_ the server.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to pass path of remote profile in case of remote webdriver. The reason being that all remote communication is handled by [command executor](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L86). Where as [browser profile](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py#L77) is dealing with local file system only. Though default profile can be [configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485709/selenium-server-not-starting-for-custom-firefox-profile?answertab=active#tab-top) on server.

Comment: But this parameter creates a copy of the profile, it doesn't use the actual profile. I'd also tried with `-browserSessionReuse` without success. Is there any way to enable session persistance between tests?

Comment: There's a way to use A remote profile, and another hacky way to have multiple profiles. What I didn't accomplish yet is to be able to pass remote profile path throuth options nor capabilities nor options.to_capabilities(). So, I've ended up with a real Firefox, with a custom -P profile, with -marionette enabled, then launching geckodriver with full set of flags, -marionete--port 2828, --connect-existing, etc.  The hacky way to have multiple profiles is to launch MANY instances of Firefox and geckodrivers using a set of profiles and ports.

Comment: If you're insterested I could elaborate a proper answer with all I have. What I can't answer is "how to pass remote profile path with remote driver", but I can answer to "open a Selenium Remote Webdriver with a specific remote profile (not temporary) "

Comment: @m3enda I ended up doing something similar and tunneling through socks. This question seems to keep getting hits, so if you want to elaborate an answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

here's what I was looking for:

```
            fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
            fp.set_preference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore")
            fp.set_preference("focusmanager.testmode", True)
            fp.update_preferences()

            driver = webdriver.Remote(
                command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
                desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'firefox', 'javascriptEnabled': True},
                browser_profile=fp
            )
```

reference:

- https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver